# On ElasticSearch, what’s a good strategy for getting one or as many document per group depending on the group

Tags: elasticsearch

I'm new to Elasticsearch, so I apologize if this question is dumb.

Say if I'm storing book pages, I want to be able to search for one page per book with the highest relevance.

My first thought is to have a type Book and Page in my index, where Book would be Page's parent in the mapping. But how do I query for n top matching pages but restrict my result to only one page per book is allowed?

Now theoretically if there are some kind of books that would allow the above query to return more than one page from that book, how should that be implemented? I think a field is needed in the Book type to indicate if multiple pages are allowed to return, but I can't wrap my head around how to formulate a query to get that result.

Answer (score 0):

A direct way is to query for each book once, and iterate through all the books.

If you don't know how many and what books you have, you can use terms aggregations first to get all the relevent books.

Typically, a search hit for top result will be returned in milliseconds. If you have 10,000 books relevent, the whole process might take several seconds. If you only have several hundreds books relevent (which is the typical order of magnitude according to the search experience on Amazon), it might take less than 1 second, which seems to be more tolerable.

Below is one possible way.

Say, if you have an index, which maps all the pages of all the books. Each page is one doc in this index (each data object are seen as 'doc' in no-sql style database, which is similar in the case of Elasticsearch). For each doc, there should be a field defined as 'the_book_belongs_to'. This field can be book_id pointing to anther index where information of every book are stored. (It might be better that books and pages are not in the same index, as they have different properties, and in the future, Elasticsearch will no longer support different _type in one index.)

When indexing done, say, you have some millions pages from some thousands of books. All the pages are in index 'pages_from_all_books_index', and all the books are in the index 'all_books_index'.

The query body might be something like

```
search_body={
    "query": {
        "bool": {
            "filter": [{"term": {"book_title.keyword": book_title}}]
            }
        },
    "size":n
}
```

book_title is the variable you can control, n is the return doc number. If you want every book return only 1 page, set n to be 1.

If you don't know which book to iterate, you can just iterate directly from all the books you have indexed, if the whole set is not too big, this won't take too long. If you have many books, it's better to do a [terms aggregations](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/search-aggregations-bucket-terms-aggregation.html) first to get all the relevent books.